# configure: error: Not found mysqlclient library

Tags: server, mysql, zabbix

When I installed ZABBIX with source code, there was an error in the compilation phase:

```
checking for main in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: Not found mysqlclient library
```

system ubuntu18.04

mysql version 5.7.28

Here are my ZABBIX compilation settings:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/home/ttg/application/zabbix-4.4 \
--enable-server \
--enable-proxy \
--enable-agent \
--enable-java \
--enable-ipv6 \
--with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
--with-net-snmp \
--with-openipmi \
--with-zlib \
--with-libpthread \
--with-libevent \
--with-ldap \
--with-libpcre \
--with-iconv \
--with-libxml2 \
--with-libcurl \
--with-libiksemel \
--with-libssh2 \
--with-mbedtls \
--with-jabber \
--with-unixodbc \
--with-ping
```

According to the solution on the network, I tested many times, but still showed the same error, such as the following method:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-devel
```

perhaps

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
```

None of these methods can solve this problem. Please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: AFAIK the package name is `libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: Yes, I may have written it wrong, but after I installed the package, I still reported an error when executing the compile command

Answer (score 1):

Install `libssl-dev` package:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

When Zabbix configure script checks if MySQL libraries are available it runs `mysql_config` which insists on using `-lssl` along with `-lmysqlclient`. So the configure test fails with this misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, but on Centos, I have installed openssl-devel and that fixed the issue. The message is indeed misleading